# REST demo with Jersey

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey

I want to make this rest service work:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

At the chapter 3.4, I want to run the service, but it seems like it's not available.
I copy-pasted the code from the tutorial.

Tomcat's error message is the following on http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available) is         not available.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the startup logs? Have you set the log level to debug?

Comment: i am also getting the same issue.
have you fixed it??

Comment: No, not yet. Still waiting for answers...

Answer (score 2):

(i) You have to make sure all your jersey jar files resides in WEB-INF instead of Libraries.

i.e

[image]

I had the same issue, when you try to add jar files it will resides in Libraries instead of lib (not sure why).

(ii) Also make sure your web.xml is mapped correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for more than one day! It turns out that the problem comes from the usage of different versions of Jersey. If you replace your web.xml content by the content I present below, it will be fine!

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>de.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>unit:WidgetPU</param-name>
     <param-value>persistence/widget</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```